# Geometrically finding a function that proves $\vert(0, \infty)\vert = \vert{(0,1)}\vert$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I came across an exercise online that showed the following proof. The exercise stated that for this to be true, we have to find a bijection $(0, \infty) \rightarrow {(0,1)}$

> Consider the interval (0, ∞) as the
> positive x-axis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let the interval (0, 1) be on the y-axis as illustrated
> in below, so that (0, ∞) and (0, 1) are perpendicular to each other.
> The figure also shows a point P = (−1, 1). Define f (x) to be the point on
> (0, 1) where the line from P to x ∈ (0, ∞) intersects the y-axis. By similar
> triangles, we have $\frac{1}{x+1} = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ so $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$

[image]

I understood the concept of coming up with $f(x)$ via similar triangles.

**1. How exactly does this ensure the function is a bijection?**

I have managed to prove this function is injective and surjective using its formula (surjectivity applies to $(0, \infty) \rightarrow {(0,1)}$).

Regarding the point $P$, I'm not sure why they chose $-1$ on the x axis. With regards to $1$ on the y axis, I can hypothesize that it's because the codomain is $(0,1)$. Also, how does $$\frac{1}{x+1} = \frac{f(x)}{x}$$ ensure $f(x)$ is a bijection?

Comment: If you've managed to show injectivity and surjectivity, then you've proven that the given $f(x)$ is indeed a bijection, as rational functions are continuous. It's also easy to find an inverse for $f$, in this case: $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$. Finally, the choice of $-1$ on the $x$-axis isn't that important, it just "makes the numbers look nicer". In fact you'll see that any $x<0$ works

Comment: @Fotis I understand but it's not easy to come up with a function like this, generally speaking. That's why I was wondering if there is a general idea I could use for other domains and their codomains.

Comment: @Fotis If you've shown surjectivity and injectivity, you've shown a bijection: continuity has nowt to do with it

Comment: @FShrike ah yes, you're right. I had homeomorphism in mind